# Making Eclipse view different file extensions as PHP

Tags: php, eclipse, ide, syntax-highlighting

I have several file extensions, like `.module`, that I would like to be understood by Eclipse to be PHP - so I get the same syntax highlighting, code completion, etc features as I would if I were editing a `.php` file. How can I do this?

I went to **Window >> Preferences >> General >> File Associations** and added `*.module` to the file types list. When I click on `*.module`, it now says the associated editors are the PHP Editor and the Text editor.

However, when I open the `*.module` file to edit it, it gives me an error message:

> Unsupported content type in editor. To
>   associate a file extension with a
>   supported content type, please see the
>   Content Types Preferences Page.

What am I doing wrong?

**fixed:** restarted Eclipse, and now it works.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Head to *Window -> Preferences*.  Drill down to *General -> Editors -> File Associations*.  From here you can add your extensions (e.g., *.module) and associate them with your preferred PHP editor.

Then restart Eclipse for the change to take effect.

Comment: I've tried this, yet I think I'm still doing something wrong (see above.)

Comment: you have to restart eclipse after doing this for the fix to take

Comment: I had to do both the General->Editors->FileAssocations edit AND the General->ContentTypes edit.  However, ContentTypes does not list a PHP Content Type (in Juno).  Instead, I found the various PHP file extensions preset in the Text->%content-type.name.() option.  This is where I added *.i to associate the old *.i files that I needed to be associated with the PHP Editor.  Also, I had to restart Eclipse.

Comment: also make sure when you close Eclipse that you don't have any of your .module files open.

Comment: I've did it by "Refreshing" project.
Then is when Eclipse recognizes file type due extension

Answer (score 17):

FYI.

window > preference > general > content types.
Expand '▷Text' and you will find 'PHP Content Type'. Select that.
Then click 'Add' and insert your own extension.

Comment: The accepted answer did not work for me, but this did work.  Using *.phpm file extension.

Comment: I had to do both the General->Editors->FileAssocations edit AND the General->ContentTypes edit.  However, ContentTypes does not list a PHP Content Type (in Juno).  Instead, I found the various PHP file extensions preset in the Text->%content-type.name.() option.  This is where I added *.i to associate the old *.i files that I needed to be associated with the PHP Editor.  Also, I had to restart Eclipse.

Comment: This one worked for me as well. I had to restart Eclipse for changes to take effect.

Answer (score 1):

Something extra to be aware of.

I had the same problem, even after installing PDT.  Turns out that there was an entry in General=>Content Types=>Text for *.php.  Note that this not under General=>Content Types=>Text=>PHP Content Type, which is placed there by PDT.  Removing the one under Text fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Window > Prefrences > General > Content Types > Text > PHP Content Type
add any type of file like *.module, *.install etc