# Make Eclipse understand that .c and .h is C++

Tags: c++, c, eclipse

I'm contributing to a project, DMD, that forces users to use .c and .h as extensions for C++ files. Is there a way to tell Eclipse that these files are actually C++?

DMD is a compiler for the D programming language at

https://github.com/D-Programming-Language/dmd

My PR for Eclipse support in DMD is at

https://github.com/D-Programming-Language/dmd/pull/4379

Comment: Why the close votes?

Comment: What is DMD? http://www.dmdproject.com/ http://www.hcii.cmu.edu/research/dmd-project http://www.gnu.org/software/dmd/

Comment: How do the other people on the DMD project get Eclipse to believe that .c files are really C++?

Comment: Does this work?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959606/making-eclipse-view-different-file-extensions-as-php

Comment: _"Why the close votes?"_ Because you have to expose a little bit more to get a concise answer.

Comment: I want the changed associations to be project specific.

Comment: Read the makefile for that project, it ought to handle it directly in there.

Comment: I've tried that through the standard *File* -> *Import* -> *Existing Code as Makefile Project* but intellisense still thinks my .c is a C source. See also https://github.com/D-Programming-Language/dmd/pull/4379